# Counting elements in JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I hope someone can point me in the right direction, I've burnt hours trying to solve what I think is a simple problem - I've hunted SO and tried various things that were close but no cigar.

I want to count two things from the sample JSON block below.

First I want to count the number of productLine entries, and second I want to count the number of types - by productLine and in total across all productLine(s).

So I'd like to end up with 3 variables with a number assigned to them to represent these three values.

Is anyone able to help?

```
var products = {
  "product": "Product Name",
  "productLines": [{
    "productLine": "Line 1",
    "types": ["Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4"]
  }, {
    "productLine": "Line 2",
    "types": ["Type 5", "Type 6", "Type 7", "Type 8"]
  }, {
    "productLine": "Line 3",
    "types": ["Type 9", "Type 10", "Type 11"]
  }, {
    "productLine": "Line 4",
    "types": ["Type 12", "Type 13"]
  }]
};
```

Output would be something like:

```
var productLineCount = 4
var productLine[0].name = "Line 1"
var productLine[0].types.count() = 4
var typesCount = 13
```

Comment: whats the expected output u want for this data? the likely format.

Comment: like what? cant get u.. @nick. You update the question itself.

Comment: Stackoverflow noob, sorry!

Comment: What if the same type occurs again in another line, does it increase the count or not?

Comment: The output you provide is JavaScript. You really want to produce code? What do you need this output for? Can you explain the context? You said you wanted *a number assigned to them*. Where is that in the expected output you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by,

```
var prodLines = products.productLines.length;
var prodLinesTypes = products.productLines.reduce(function(a,b){ 
       return a + (b.types.length) 
}, 0);

console.log(prodLines); //4
console.log(prodLinesTypes); //13
```

The first one is an obvious one, that is reading the length of an array. But the second one can be done by using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It can be done in many ways. But I would suggest you to go with reduce at this context.

Comment: Thank you @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy - I tried this (will have to work my way through the second one and understand it) but the first line gave me a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' - any idea?

Comment: @NickMyers That is because of your inconsistent property name, look at the last object in the array, It has a property called `type` whereas others has `types`.

Comment: Maybe it's one of these 'Oh dang someone answered before I could post my answer so I'll downvote them' downvotes. We can only assume.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` loop and return results in one object

```js
var products = {
  "product": "Product Name",
  "productLines": [{
    "productLine": "Line 1",
    "types": ["Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4"]
  }, {
    "productLine": "Line 2",
    "types": ["Type 5", "Type 6", "Type 7", "Type 8"]
  }, {
    "productLine": "Line 3",
    "types": ["Type 9", "Type 10", "Type 11"]
  }, {
    "productLine": "Line 4",
    "types": ["Type 12", "Type 13"]
  }]
};

var result = {}
products.productLines.forEach(function(e) {
  result.totalLines = (result.totalLines || 0) + 1;
  e.types.forEach(function(a) {
    result.totalTypes = (result.totalTypes || 0) + 1;
    result[e.productLine + 'Types'] = (result[e.productLine + 'Types'] || 0) + 1;
  });
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an custom api like

```
getter(index, type)
```

index is the product index, type can be either `typeCount` or `name`.

```js
var products = {
  "product": "Product Name",
  "productLines": [{
    "productLine": "Line 1",
    "types": ["Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4"]
  }, {
    "productLine": "Line 2",
    "types": ["Type 5", "Type 6", "Type 7", "Type 8"]
  }, {
    "productLine": "Line 3",
    "types": ["Type 9", "Type 10", "Type 11"]
  }, {
    "productLine": "Line 4",
    "types": ["Type 12", "Type 13"]
  }]
};

var count = 0;
for (var i = 0, len =  products.productLines.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  count += products.productLines[i].types.length;
}
console.log('productLineCount: ',len);
console.log('typesCount: ', count);

function getter(index, type) {
  var res,
      arr = products.productLines[index];
  if (type === 'name') {
      res = arr.productLine;
  }
  else if (type === 'typeCount') {
    res = arr.types.length;
  }
  return res;
}


console.log('productLine[0].name: ', getter(0, 'name'));
console.log('productLine[0].types.count(): ', getter(0, 'typeCount'));
/*console.log('productLine[1].name: ', getter(1, 'name'));
console.log('productLine[1].types.count(): ', getter(1, 'typeCount'));
console.log('productLine[2].name: ', getter(2, 'name'));
console.log('productLine[2].types.count(): ', getter(2, 'typeCount'));*/
```

Comment: hey @nick does this work? Please validate if we need some other improvements here.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the three counts as follows:

```
var productLineCount = products.productLines.length;
var productTypesCount = products.productLines.map(line => line.types.length);
var totalTypesCount = productTypesCount.reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur, 0);
```

```js
var products = {
  "product": "Product Name",
  "productLines": [{
    "productLine": "Line 1",
    "types": ["Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4"]
  }, {
    "productLine": "Line 2",
    "types": ["Type 5", "Type 6", "Type 7", "Type 8"]
  }, {
    "productLine": "Line 3",
    "types": ["Type 9", "Type 10", "Type 11"]
  }, {
    "productLine": "Line 4",
    "types": ["Type 12", "Type 13"]
  }]
};

var productLineCount = products.productLines.length;
var productTypesCount = products.productLines.map(line => line.types.length);
var totalTypesCount = productTypesCount.reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur, 0);

console.log('productLineCount', productLineCount);
console.log('productTypesCount', productTypesCount);
console.log('totalTypesCount', totalTypesCount);
```

Comment: thanks for this - really useful to see this approach

Answer (score 0):

For counting the ProductLines you can do it

```
number_of_productLines = products.productLines.length
```

And for counting the types by productLines you can do:

```
productlines_types_count = [] # List of {'productline': name, 'length': int}
products.productLines.forEach(function(productline){ 
    productlines_types_count.push({'productline': productline.productLine, 'length': productline.types.length})
});
```

Also fix your json, the last of objects has a 'type' id insteade of 'types':

```
var products = 
  {
    "product" : "Product Name",
    "productLines": [
      {
        "productLine" : "Line 1",
        "types": ["Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4"]
      },
      {
        "productLine": "Line 2",
        "types": ["Type 5", "Type 6", "Type 7", "Type 8"]
      },
      {
        "productLine": "Line 3",
        "types": ["Type 9", "Type 10", "Type 11"]
      },
      {
        "productLine": "Line 4",
        "types": ["Type 12", "Type 13"] #here
      }]
   };
```